# Как центрировать все по вертикали CSS

Tags: html, css

Нужно отцентровать весь текст с кнопкой по вертикали. Пробовал много способов, но так ничего не получилось.

```css
body {
 background: #cc3354;
 color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 36pt;
 margin-bottom: -15px;
}
.parent {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px;
    max-width: 1000px;
} 
.child {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 40px;
}
button {
 border-color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 20pt;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background: #cc3354;
 padding: 10;
 border: 2px solid #ffffff;
 height: 42px;
 width: 140px;
}
a:link {
 color: #ffffff;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.button-size {
 width:100%;
}
.button-location {
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Внимание</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <style type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
   <div class="button-size">
    <h1>Внимание</h1>
    <p>Русский писатель, философ и общественный деятель XIX века Владимир Одоевский в незаконченном утопическом романе «4338-й год», написанном в 1837 году, похоже, первым предсказал появление современных блогов и интернета: в тексте романа есть строки: «между знакомыми домами устроены магнетические телеграфы, посредством которых живущие на далёком расстоянии общаются друг с другом».</p>
    <button class="button-location"><a class="button" href="http://site.com">Перейти</a></button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Код почему-то не работает в Stack Overflow. Скорее всего из-за Google Fonts. Запускайте код отдельно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я всё верно понял, то вам нужно центрировать контент страницы по вертикали.
В таком случае, ваша проблема в том, что **высота страницы подстраивается под высоту контента**.
Данный код решаем вашу проблему:

```
/* Вытягиваем саму страницу */
html{ height: 100%; width: 100%; }
body {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    background: #cc3354;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;

    /* Вытягиваем body на всю высоту страницы */
    height: 100%;
    position: relative; display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* Выравниваем по вертикали */
}
```

**Но!** Данный способ является, скажем так, не самым правильным. Лучше всего будет создать контейнер для элементов, и растянуть его на всю страницу, как в вашем коде я сделал с HTML.

Тот же код, но с вендорными префиксами:

```
/* Вытягиваем саму страницу */
html{ height: 100%; width: 100%; }
body {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    background: #cc3354;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;

    /* Вытягиваем body на всю высоту страницы */
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;

    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center; /* Выравниваем по вертикали */
}
```

*И, на будущее, в браузерах, по крайней мере в хроме, есть инструменты разработчика, в которых, в свою очередь, есть инспектор элементов, пользуйтесь им чаще.*

Comment: Лучший просто! Я эту проблему долго не мог решить. Инспектором элементов я пользовался, но мне было не своем понятно, зачем он нужен. Теперь понял. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
.button-size {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Это должно решить проблему.

Comment: Увы, но нет. Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Я не вижу, конечно, результата верстки вашей, но попробуйте дать эти свойства классу выше, если не тот, то еще выше. В общем, эти свойства надо дать контейнеру, внутри которого должно происходить позиционирование контента. И флоаты, конечно, нужно срочно убирать. Это хак, который был придуман задолго до флексов и гридов.

Comment: @AlexSazonov justify-content: center; центрирует по горизонтали а align-items по вертикали

Answer (score 0):

```
.button-size {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; // центрирование по горизонтали 
  align-items: center; // центрирование по вертикали 
}
```